# Match two object keys and display another object key value in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objects

i have two objects like this

```
languages = [
  {
    "name": "english",
    "iso_639_2_code": "eng"
  },
  {
    "name": "esperanto",
    "iso_639_2_code": "epo"
  },
  {
    "name": "estonian",
    "iso_639_2_code": "est"
  }
]
```

and another is

```
user = [
    { 
    name: "john",
    language: "eng",
    country: "US"
   }   
];
```

what i have to do is, match iso_639_2_code to language of user then, i have to display Language name not code from languages. basically both are different api, and i have no idea how to do it this in angular 4.
here's a link what i am trying https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9k2nff?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array find:

```js
var languages = [
    {"name": "english", "iso_639_2_code": "eng"},
    {"name": "esperanto","iso_639_2_code": "epo"},
    {"name": "estonian","iso_639_2_code": "est"}
];
var user = [{name: "john",language: "eng",country: "US"}];

var language = languages.find(l => l.iso_639_2_code === user[0].language);
var languageName = language && language.name; // <-- also prevent error when there is no corresponding language found
console.log(languageName);
```

EDIT:

With multiple user, it will be:

```js
var languages = [
    {"name": "english", "iso_639_2_code": "eng"},
    {"name": "esperanto","iso_639_2_code": "epo"},
    {"name": "estonian","iso_639_2_code": "est"}
];
var users = [
    {name: "john",language: "eng",country: "US"},
    {name: "john",language: "epo",country: "Esperanto"}
];

var languageNames = languages.filter(
    l => users.find(u => l.iso_639_2_code === u.language)
).map(lang => lang.name);

console.log(languageNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`

```
var output = languages.find(s => s.iso_639_2_code == user[0].language).name;
```

**Demo**

```js
var languages = [{
    "name": "english",
    "iso_639_2_code": "eng"
  },
  {
    "name": "esperanto",
    "iso_639_2_code": "epo"
  },
  {
    "name": "estonian",
    "iso_639_2_code": "est"
  }
];
var user = [{
    name: "john",
    language: "eng",
    country: "US"
  }

];

var output = languages.find(s => s.iso_639_2_code == user[0].language).name;

console.log(output);
```

Or, if there are multiple users, and you want to find language name for each of them, then use `map`

```
var output = user.map(t => 
   languages.find(s => 
      s.iso_639_2_code == t.language).name);
```

**Demo**

```js
var languages = [{
    "name": "english",
    "iso_639_2_code": "eng"
  },
  {
    "name": "esperanto",
    "iso_639_2_code": "epo"
  },
  {
    "name": "estonian",
    "iso_639_2_code": "est"
  }
];
var user = [{
    name: "john",
    language: "eng",
    country: "US"
  }

];

var output = user.map(t => 
   languages.find(s => 
      s.iso_639_2_code == t.language).name);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you need , for output just run the snippet :

```js
var languages = [
  {
    "name": "english",
    "iso_639_2_code": "eng"
  },
  {
    "name": "esperanto",
    "iso_639_2_code": "epo"
  },
  {
    "name": "estonian",
    "iso_639_2_code": "est"
  }
];

var user = [
    { 
    name: "john",
    language: "eng",
    country: "US"
   }

];

user.map(u => {
  let flang = languages.filter(lang => lang.iso_639_2_code === u.language);
  if(flang) {
    u.language = flang[0].name;
  }
  return u;
})

console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var languages=[
        {"name":"english","iso_639_2_code":"eng"}, 
        {"name":"esperanto","iso_639_2_code":"epo"}, 
        {"name":"estonian","iso_639_2_code":"est"}
    ];
    var user=[
        {name:"john",language:"eng",country:"US"}
    ];
    var languageFound = languages.find(lang => lang.iso_639_2_code === user[0].language);
    if(languageFound){
      var languageName = languageFound.name;
      console.log(languageName);
    }
```